# How to get text position (in pixels) in TMemo?

Tags: delphi, winapi, scroll, memo, tmemo

I want to get the position/placement in pixels of a text (aWord) in a TMemo. My code is something like this:

```
var
 Size: TSize;
 Pt: Cardinal;
 aWord: string;
 x, y: Integer;
begin
 ...
 Pt := Perform(EM_POSFROMCHAR, aStart-1, 0);
 Windows.GetTextExtentPoint32(DC, PChar(aWord), aLen, Size);
 x:= Smallint(LoWord(Pt));
 y:= Smallint(HiWord(Pt));
```

Initially it works ok, but when I scroll down the memo, I get a range check error on the last line.

How to I get the position when I scroll down?

---

The official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms908369(v=msdn.10)) says:

> A returned coordinate can be negative if the character has been
>   scrolled outside the client area of the edit control. The coordinates
>   are truncated to integer values.

I don't know how to interpret this.

Comment: `LoWord` and `HiWord` treat `DWORD` halves as unsigned numbers and return values in the range from 0 to 65535. You get range errors when assigning values greater than 32767 to `Smallint`. You can correct this by assigning `LoWord` to `x` directly, and correct it manually: `if x > 32767 then x = x - 65536;`.

Answer (score 2):

Silly. My mind got stuck on "The coordinates are truncated to integer values" - which I still don't know what it means. I was trying to convert those coordinates.

The solution is silly: if we get a negative number, it means that the text is outside the screen. We don't try to extract/convert the Loword and HiWord. We simply exit the procedure.

---

Also Pt should be "NativeInt".

Comment: Actually, `Pt` should rather be `LRESULT`